# Is there an easy way to be notified when a LinkedIn connection disconnects?

Tags: linkedin, notifications

It would be nice to be notified when a LinkedIn connection decided to dis-connect.

Presently when I notice the number of connections change, I scan through my address book in LI to see who is on Linked in and not a connection.  Tedious.

Comment: I personally would like the disconnect to go under the radar, you often disconnect for a reason and I'm not obliged to explain myself ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there isn't a (native) solution to get notified when someone disconnects from you on LinkedIn.

However, I would also think it's inappropriate. It's like saying:

> I no longer want to talk to you! Kthxbye!

Furthermore, what use does it have, if that person actively decided no longer to be in touch with you, it's unlikely you can change his mind (or not worth trying)

Comment: I've occasionally disconnected from someone who I didn't talk to very much any more, and if they had contacted me immediately after I would have reconsidered. (This actually happened to me, but AFAIK LI doesn't allow you to re-connect).
Additionally, it is nice to know if someone *doesn't* want to connect to you.  You can avoid emailing them later.

Comment: Fair enough, off course the semantics from disconnecting and defriending might be a little different (when looking at FaceBook)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same question and couldn't find an answer. I would believe it *is* possible to track that programmatically (through an app) - though it's not done natively in LinkedIn, of course where everything is about connection, not disconnection. I haven't found an external app yet that does such a check, but if someone has, please share that with us.

I don't see a particular problem with tracking disconnections as Ivo did, because it's technically possible and it's already done in other social networks such as Twitter (through twunfollow.com) and Facebook. Liz Ryan offered [three good reasons to snip a LinkedIn connection](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/liz-ryan/three-good-reasons-to-sni_b_1231542.html). So why shouldn't I get to know if someone doesn't want to be my contact anymore?

In addition, I don't see LinkedIn these days so much as a purely business social network anymore (it actually bewilders me that LinkedIn sees itself this way). Lots of my LinkedIn contacts are friends, who I keep in touch with because *this* is the network we share (plus, I don't like Facebook).

So, in short, at this stage there doesn't appear to be any automatic way to track LinkedIn disconnections. If I get around to develop one, or find one, I'll post it here.